# CodeIgniter Database Query Has An Error But I Don't See It

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
if ($this->input->get('beds')) 
    $where['Bedrooms'] = $this->input->get('beds');

if ($this->input->get('baths'))
    $where['Bathrooms'] = $this->input->get('baths');

$min_price = ($this->input->get('min_price')) 
    ? $this->input->get('min_price')
    : '0';

$max_price = ($this->input->get('max_price'))
    ? $this->input->get('max_price')
    : '10000000';

$q = $this->db->select("*")
    ->where('ListingPrice <=', $max_price)
    ->where('ListingPrice >=', $min_price)
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Do you? You can trust that all the values are there.

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ListingPrice <= '100000' AND ListingPrice >= '0' LIMIT 10' at line 2

Comment: Well, what error message are you getting? What isn't working?

Comment: I don't use CodeIgniter but there doesn't seem to be a `FROM` element to your query

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `ListingPrice` <= '100000' AND `ListingPrice` >= '0' LIMIT 10' at line 2

Comment: Clive, give that answer as an actual answer and I'll accept it. Doh! You were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use CodeIgniter but there doesn't seem to be a `FROM` element to your query

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify the table you are querying from. Try setting the table name inside the get method or using the `from()` method somewhere in your query.

```
->get('table_name');
```

Also, if you are just selecting everything ("*") you can leave out the `select()` from your query because it will select everything by default.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're mixing the **MODEL** within the **CONTROLLER** also try using the profiler to get more details on your 'error' => $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

Otherwise you are missing the FROM:
`$q = $this->db->select('*')->from('TABLE')....`